# How to get in VBA the max value of the cells in the row range 2:60 and column range D:H

Tags: excel, row, range, max, vba

I am having an Excel sheet with integer values in 60 rows and in 7 columns. First row is the commentaire, and first three columns are the commentaires as well (I have to ommit those).

So, I would like to iterate through the row range 2:60 in column range 3:7 (D:H) to find the max value of the celles in a row. Answer goes to the celles in the column I.

What I have (simplified view):

```
       Test1  Test2  Test3  Test4
One    1      2      3      4
Two    5      6      7      8
Three  1      2      5      4
Four   1      7      3      4
```

What I would like to have:

```
       Test1  Test2  Test3  Test4  Max
One    1      2      3      4      4
Two    5      6      7      8      8
Three  1      2      5      4      5 
Four   1      7      3      4      7
```

If I create a macro manually, I receive this:

```
range("D2:I2").Select
range("I2").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"

range("D3:I3").Select
range("I3").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"

range("D4:I4").Select
range("I4").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
```

Cool... but I would like to iterate through that with a loop.

I tried this, but doesnt work:

```
Sub max()
    For num = 2 To 4
        range("D&num:I&num").Select
        range("I & num").Activate
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
    Next num
End Sub
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: try to change `range("D&num:I&num").Select` to `range("D" & num ":I" & num).Select` and `range("I & num").Activate` to `range("I" &  num).Activate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simoco has already mentioned what the error in your code is. I would also add that you should avoid the use of `.Activate`. You might want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

The most simplest way would be to use this which doesn't use looping

```
Sub Sample()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName")
        .Range("I2:I60").Formula = "=Max(D2:H2)"
    End With
End Sub
```